# Validation accuracy and f1 score remain constant right from first epoch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have used ResNet50 for an image classification for 5 classes. The training loss decreases over the epochs and also the training accuracy increases but the validation_accuracy remains stagnant and the validation_loss keeps hovering at some high value. Is there something i am doing wrong here in the code below?

I have tried using different learning rates. Tried adding BatchNorm and Dropout layers. Also ensure that the data i am passing is clean and properly structured. Specified the batch size and also used shuffle=True for validation but nothing seems to help. Any help on this would be very valuable.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.python.keras import callbacks
import time
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers

resnet_weights_path = './clean_resnet_data/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'


data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                                    vertical_flip=True,
                                    zoom_range=0.3,
                                    rescale=1. / 255
                                   )

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

image_size = 512
batch_size = 16
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        './org_train',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        #batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './valid_org',
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')

num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)

Found 1204 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 250 images belonging to 5 classes.
5


model = Sequential()

model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

model.layers[0].trainable = False
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Model)             (None, 2048)              23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               1049088   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 256)               1024      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 1285      
=================================================================
Total params: 24,772,485
Trainable params: 1,183,237
Non-trainable params: 23,589,248
_________________________________________________________________

count = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk("./org_train/")])
steps_in_each_epoch=int(count/batch_size) + 1

#setting callback parameters for model saving, early stopping and reduce_lr
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('resnet50_clean_data.model',monitor='f1', 
                                   mode = 'max', save_best_only=True, verbose=2)


log_dir = './tf-log/newdata_withlr_nodrop'

tb_cb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=0)


early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1', mode = 'max',patience=15, verbose=2)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_f1', mode = 'max',factor=0.5, patience=3, min_lr=0.00001, verbose=2)

cbks = [early_stopping,reduce_lr]


from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers

# adam
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.003)

# compile
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=adam,metrics=["accuracy",f1])

model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=150,validation_data=validation_generator,callbacks=cbks)

Output:

Epoch 1/150
38/38 [==============================] - 86s 2s/step - loss: 1.5320 - acc: 0.3364 - f1: 0.3989 - val_loss: 5.5517 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2000
Epoch 2/150
38/38 [==============================] - 70s 2s/step - loss: 1.2850 - acc: 0.4567 - f1: 0.4663 - val_loss: 4.4173 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2100
Epoch 3/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.2396 - acc: 0.4583 - f1: 0.4716 - val_loss: 4.7810 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2658
Epoch 4/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.2147 - acc: 0.4973 - f1: 0.4902 - val_loss: 4.2491 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2667
Epoch 5/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.1994 - acc: 0.5082 - f1: 0.4982 - val_loss: 3.5541 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2667
Epoch 6/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.1525 - acc: 0.5284 - f1: 0.5116 - val_loss: 3.8147 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2667
Epoch 7/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.1658 - acc: 0.5014 - f1: 0.5104 - val_loss: 3.4530 - val_acc: 0.1920 - val_f1: 0.2784
Epoch 8/150
38/38 [==============================] - 77s 2s/step - loss: 1.1181 - acc: 0.5222 - f1: 0.5137 - val_loss: 3.1350 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2083
Epoch 9/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.0760 - acc: 0.5543 - f1: 0.5402 - val_loss: 2.5362 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2000
Epoch 10/150
37/38 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 1.1092 - acc: 0.5331 - f1: 0.5335
Epoch 00010: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.001500000013038516.
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.1155 - acc: 0.5322 - f1: 0.5329 - val_loss: 2.5705 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.1993
Epoch 11/150
38/38 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 1.0541 - acc: 0.5623 - f1: 0.5438 - val_loss: 2.2404 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2180
Epoch 12/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.0180 - acc: 0.5630 - f1: 0.5421 - val_loss: 2.0331 - val_acc: 0.2480 - val_f1: 0.2733
Epoch 13/150
37/38 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 1.0070 - acc: 0.5992 - f1: 0.5508
Epoch 00013: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.000750000006519258.
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.0071 - acc: 0.6006 - f1: 0.5513 - val_loss: 1.9989 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2037
Epoch 14/150
38/38 [==============================] - 76s 2s/step - loss: 1.0195 - acc: 0.5523 - f1: 0.5082 - val_loss: 2.0054 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2001
Epoch 15/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 1.0127 - acc: 0.5982 - f1: 0.5079 - val_loss: 2.1047 - val_acc: 0.2040 - val_f1: 0.2143
Epoch 16/150
37/38 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.9787 - acc: 0.5934 - f1: 0.5173
Epoch 00016: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.000375000003259629.
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.9776 - acc: 0.5918 - f1: 0.5183 - val_loss: 2.2156 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2705
Epoch 17/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.9950 - acc: 0.5956 - f1: 0.4904 - val_loss: 2.2039 - val_acc: 0.2000 - val_f1: 0.2622
Epoch 18/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.9451 - acc: 0.6174 - f1: 0.5297 - val_loss: 2.2094 - val_acc: 0.1960 - val_f1: 0.2689
Epoch 19/150
37/38 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.9531 - acc: 0.6182 - f1: 0.5106
Epoch 00019: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.0001875000016298145.
38/38 [==============================] - 78s 2s/step - loss: 0.9566 - acc: 0.6168 - f1: 0.5065 - val_loss: 2.1872 - val_acc: 0.2080 - val_f1: 0.2652
Epoch 20/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.9706 - acc: 0.5898 - f1: 0.4943 - val_loss: 2.1983 - val_acc: 0.2080 - val_f1: 0.2658
Epoch 21/150
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.9365 - acc: 0.5958 - f1: 0.4986 - val_loss: 2.1936 - val_acc: 0.1960 - val_f1: 0.2416
Epoch 22/150
37/38 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.9472 - acc: 0.6068 - f1: 0.4861
Epoch 00022: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 9.375000081490725e-05.
38/38 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.9457 - acc: 0.6097 - f1: 0.4884 - val_loss: 2.1958 - val_acc: 0.1960 - val_f1: 0.2428
Epoch 00022: early stopping
```

The behavior of the Validation set is confusing. I don't understand why the validation accuracy or the validation f1 does not change at all since the first epoch(remain constant). What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you try `setting model.layers[0].trainable = True` and check if it helps. Thanks!